# How does one understand Data vs Record capabilities in agda?

Tags: types, record, agda, type-theory

Why doesn't a custom unit type allow us to prove this basic left unit law?  I see the only difference between my implementation and that of the standard library is the use of `Record` vs `Data` inductive inductive type former.  I don't understand why the `Data` won't allow me to prove this basic left identity lemma, which should be true definitionally.  Does it have to do with `Record`'s automatic eta inheritance?  If so, why is this the case?  Is it possible to prove this without the builtin (e.g. `Record`) Unit type? In general, is this a limitation of `Data`, or is it possible to do everything in agda modulo records?

```
data _≡_ {A : Set} : A → A → Set where
  refl : (a : A) → a ≡ a

--from builtin
lunitm : (f : ⊤ → ⊤) → (λ x → f tt) ≡ f
lunitm f = refl (λ x → tt)

data ⊤2 : Set where
  tt2 : ⊤2

lunitm2 : (f : ⊤2 → ⊤2) → (λ x → f tt2) ≡ f
lunitm2 f = ? --refl ? --can't instantiate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed due to `⊤2` being a `data` rather than `record`.

Agda implements eta-rules for [negative types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/negative+type).

Records are negative and so have eta-rules associated with them. The eta-rule of

```
record Unit : Set where
  constructor unit
```

is

```
_ : (u : Unit) -> u ≡ unit
_ = λ u -> refl
```

Supporting eta-equality for positive types is [possible in theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sum+type#as_a_positive_type), but Agda does not implement that.

Comment: so is it possible for a user to manually implement an eta equality for a given positively defined type, or does that need to be done at the meta (i.e. language implenetation) layer of abstraction?

Comment: @WarrickMacmillan in the general case proving equalities and teaching the type checker about them is called equality reflection. Agda has some support for such trickery via `REWRITE` rules, see [Hack your type theory with rewrite rules](https://jesper.sikanda.be/posts/hack-your-type-theory.html) for one example. But I don't know if it's possible to implement an eta rule for a data type this way as `REWRITE` rules are somewhat limited in what equalities are accepted in them.